# Почему я не могу отправлять сообщения?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Я хотел добавить пост, но получил такую ошибку

> You can only post once every 90 minutes.

Я ждал 2 часа. Все равно эта ошибка была. Я подождал день, все равно эта ошибка была.

Что мне делать? Кстати, пытался создать пост на английском стеке.

Comment: Скриншотик был бы в тему, как дополнение к вопросу. Это нужно, чтобы видеть проблему в момент её возникновения.

Comment: Хорошо если появиться подобное то скину.

Comment: На каком конкретно сайте сети возникла ошибка? На ruSO эта строка должна быть на русском языке.

Comment: ip-адрес неуникальный и кто-то другой с него писал.

Comment: на английском SO.com

Comment: Ответ на вопрос "почему" можете получить [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/339911).